# Google tag manager on Magento2 - Double GTAG ID on my site

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager

I'm facing a particular problem with google tag manager.
In the error console the browser gives me this type of error:

```
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1XXXXXXX&l=dataLayer&cx=c net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I tried to search but I couldn't understand why tag manager calls two gtag ids, one of these is invalid and in fact the 404 error returns.

These are the scripts that Google Tag Manager explodes at me:

```
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1XXXXXXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2XXXXXXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>

<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/destination?id=G-1XXXXXXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/destination?id=G-2XXXXXXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>
```

Why does tag manager return two links with two different gtag ids?
My site is with Magento2 and the module that GA4 manages is called WeltPixel.

I searched the whole site but couldn't find this gtag id which is causing the error. How can I do?

Comment: Have you try by disabling that WeltPixel extensions?

Comment: This is not good man. I want WeltPixel in my site